# How to share authentication information across multiple rails apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, single-sign-on, omniauth

How to share authentication information across multiple rails apps

We use omniauth, devise gems to enable authentication across (facebook, twitter, salesforce, regular user, LDAP, Microsoft Active Directory). We have multiple rails apps and would like to re-use authentication + authorization (cancan) using SSO. How should we go about supporting this?

Comment: Have a look at [shibboleth-rails](https://github.com/ASCTech/shibboleth-rails)

Comment: The above project doesn't seem to be active though.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an OAuth 2 provider with [Doorkeeper](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper), either setting it up on the app that currently handles authentication, or extract it as a separate app that only deals with authentication.

Then you can create your own OmniAuth strategy which you can use in all your apps.

Comment: I am assuming I should be able to enforce an omniauth strategy for facebook | twitter | salesforce. How about LDAP or Active Directory

Comment: Your central authorization server will handle all your existing authentication methods, they will be hidden from your other applications. The client applications will only need a single OmniAuth strategy so it can talk to your authorization server.

Comment: This is how the flow would look like: User goes to one of your apps, clicks login. It is redirected to your authorization server, where he is offered to authenticate with Facebook/LDAP/etc. When that's done, the authorization server redirects back to the client, the client validates the details and retrieves user info in the background via a REST API, and remembers the current user ID in the session.